# Can ELB send requests from two different IPs simultaneously?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I use mod_rpaf to get the real IPs in the logs. However, it requires load balancers IP. Earlier, I used to see the "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0" useragent to get the ELB's IP. But, strangely today I can see two health check requests every time on each of the instances from two different IPs. My ELB and the EC2 instances are in same availability zone.

Anyone faced a similar situation? Is this an expected behavior or some anomaly?

Comment: are your instance(s) registered on two different ELBs ?

Comment: Nope. I had only one ELB. This is not happening as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal to see a variety of ELB IP addresses.  ELBs scale up and down with traffic to your site and those actions will cause you to see different IP addresses.

Using mod_rpaf with ELB is never going to be a reliable solution.

If you want to know the source IP that the ELB saw, then you can use use the last value from teh X-Forwarded-For list.

See also [this blog post](http://tech.superhappykittymeow.com/?p=281) for a patch to mod_rpaf.

Comment: I understand that changing the ELB IP is due to the scaling activities. But, that won't cause different IPs at the same time.

Comment: You will see multiple IPs when AWS uses multiple ELB instances to front your site and you will see them change as the ELB scales up and down.  I run a high traffic site and I currently see traffic from 5 distinct upstream ELBs IPs.